# Create library for repetitive functionality in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter-3

I want to create a library of repetitive functionality in CodeIgniter, so that that functionality will be automatically available in the next project. So how can I do that?

For example, suppose that I want to create a login library. How could I create a library for "Login" so that it will be readily available in the next project?

Comment: Check [Ion_auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) which is already created by one of CI council members.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **modular structure** for code Igniter , this is best for code **Reusability** and **Extendibility**

Please go through this link for more information `http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application--net-11850`